# how does Javascript evaluate methods with the same name?

Tags: javascript

I am confused about something with Javascript. I am sorry if it's a silly question.

Let's say I have an addressFind.js file in "/script" directory and there are **utilities.js** and **utils.js** files as well. In addressFind.js file I am calling the **getElement()** method of **utilities.js** file. However, another developer added the same **getElement()** method in **utils.js** file (accidentally).

In this case, how is Javascript going to behave? Which getElement() addressFind.js is going to use? Would it throw any exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions behave the same way as other objects (of course, they are objects themselves): the newer with the same name will redefine the old one. That's why it is best practice to not pollute the global namespace, and implement proper namespacing and/or modules.